# Postgres SQL Installation

Tags: postgresql

I installed Postgres SQL as the root user and created the user Database for it. 
I am trying to access the database from a non-root account through a Linux Redhat system. 
The software I installed requires you to connect with the database and give output in web page. While i am running the shell script from the non root where i installed the software, it gives the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/illumina/apps/galaxy/galaxy-dist/lib/galaxy/webapps/galaxy/buildapp.py", line 35, in app_factory
    app = UniverseApplication( global_conf = global_conf, **kwargs )
  File "/illumina/apps/galaxy/galaxy-dist/lib/galaxy/app.py", line 51, in __init__
    create_or_verify_database( db_url, kwargs.get( 'global_conf', {} ).get( '__file__', None ), self.config.database_engine_options, app=self )
  File "/illumina/apps/galaxy/galaxy-dist/lib/galaxy/model/migrate/check.py", line 50, in create_or_verify_database
    dataset_table = Table( "dataset", meta, autoload=True )
  File "/illumina/apps/galaxy/galaxy-dist/eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.5.6_dev_r6498-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 108, in __call__
    return type.__call__(self, name, metadata, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/illumina/apps/galaxy/galaxy-dist/eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.5.6_dev_r6498-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 236, in __init__
    _bind_or_error(metadata).reflecttable(self, include_columns=include_columns)
  File "/illumina/apps/galaxy/galaxy-dist/eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.5.6_dev_r6498-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1261, in reflecttable
    conn = self.contextual_connect()
  File "/illumina/apps/galaxy/galaxy-dist/eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.5.6_dev_r6498-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/threadlocal.py", line 194, in contextual_connect
    return self.session.get_connection(**kwargs)
  File "/illumina/apps/galaxy/galaxy-dist/eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.5.6_dev_r6498-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/threadlocal.py", line 20, in get_connection
    return self.engine.TLConnection(self, self.engine.pool.connect(), close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "/illumina/apps/galaxy/galaxy-dist/eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.5.6_dev_r6498-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 151, in connect
    agent = _ConnectionFairy(self)
  File "/illumina/apps/galaxy/galaxy-dist/eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.5.6_dev_r6498-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 304, in __init__
    rec = self._connection_record = pool.get()
  File "/illumina/apps/galaxy/galaxy-dist/eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.5.6_dev_r6498-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 161, in get
    return self.do_get()
  File "/illumina/apps/galaxy/galaxy-dist/eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.5.6_dev_r6498-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 639, in do_get
    con = self.create_connection()
  File "/illumina/apps/galaxy/galaxy-dist/eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.5.6_dev_r6498-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 122, in create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/illumina/apps/galaxy/galaxy-dist/eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.5.6_dev_r6498-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 198, in __init__
    self.connection = self.__connect()
  File "/illumina/apps/galaxy/galaxy-dist/eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.5.6_dev_r6498-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 261, in __connect
    connection = self.__pool._creator()
  File "/illumina/apps/galaxy/galaxy-dist/eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.5.6_dev_r6498-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 80, in connect
    raise exc.DBAPIError.instance(None, None, e)
OperationalError: (OperationalError) FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "galaxy"
 None None
```

Please help me find out which is right:

1. whether Postgresql is installed properly and I can use it from a non-root user.
2. Should I uninstall Postgresql from root and reinstall it in a non-root account? When I tried to install using a non-root account it replied " user is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."

Thanks
Sridhar

Answer (score 1):

```
 OperationalError: (OperationalError) FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "galaxy" None None
```

Indicates that its trying to connect as user "galaxy". Check if you are able to do the following

1. Connect as "galaxy" from the postgress CLI prompt
2. If you are able to do #1 then check if your username and password are correct in your connection parameters for python.

Comment: Hi,                                                                   Thanks for the Reply.. I am new to the database could you please explain how to check it..

Comment: @sridhar Have you read the Postgres documentation? particularly [the man page for `psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html)?